# How do I get cells in List Control to have a border?

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to get something like this:
[image]

But I've been stuck looking for a solution for 2 hours now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines are just an additional style to set:

```
DWORD dwStyle = m_list.GetExtendedStyle();
dwStyle |= LVS_EX_GRIDLINES;
m_list.SetExtendedStyle(dwStyle);
```